# python ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (389,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (389,7)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, lstm

I am new to python programming language I am using Pytorch neural network LSTM to predict the feature price of the stock i know it's a common question but I am not being able to fix the issue

**ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (389,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (389,7)**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

from torch.autograd import Variable
# Importing the training set
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('data/trraining_set.csv')
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:,[1,2,5,6,7,8,9]].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(INPUT_SIZE, 766):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-INPUT_SIZE:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

# Reshaping
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, i_size, h_size, n_layers, o_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=i_size,
            hidden_size=h_size,
            num_layers=n_layers
        )
        self.out = nn.Linear(h_size, o_size)

    def forward(self, x, h_state):
        r_out, hidden_state = self.rnn(x, h_state)

        hidden_size = hidden_state[-1].size(-1)
        r_out = r_out.view(-1, hidden_size)
        outs = self.out(r_out)

        return outs, hidden_state
rnn = RNN(INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, NUM_LAYERS, OUTPUT_SIZE)

optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

hidden_state = None

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X_train).float())
    labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train).float())

    output, hidden_state = rnn(inputs, hidden_state) 

    loss = criterion(output.view(-1), labels)
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)                     
    optimiser.step()                                     

    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch,loss.item()))

dataset_test = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')
real_stock_price = dataset_test.iloc[:,[1,2,5,6,7,8,9]].values



dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - INPUT_SIZE :].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(INPUT_SIZE, 329):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-INPUT_SIZE:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
```

here is the following error

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-249ca96baddc> in <module>
      8 inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - INPUT_SIZE :].values
      9 inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
---> 10 inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
     11 X_test = []
     12 for i in range(INPUT_SIZE, 329):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in transform(self, X)
    412                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    413 
--> 414         X *= self.scale_
    415         X += self.min_
    416         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (389,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (389,7)
```

Comment: Formatting, grammar, and replace an appropriate label

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the error with:

```
In [75]: x = np.ones((4,1))                                                                      
In [76]: x *= np.ones((4,2))                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-43b4c8414f68> in <module>
----> 1 x *= np.ones((4,2))

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (4,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (4,2)
```

In a `*=` expression, the shape of the RHS is fixed, even it has a size 1 dimension.  So it's "non-broadcastable".

Looks like the training_set has 7 columns.  But `inputs` after the reshape has only 1.  If `sc` has been trained on a dataset with 7 'features', the test values also have to have 7 'features'.